# UIView shows perfect on iPhone but not on iPad

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

I am pretty new to `iOS` development and I am able to create `views` and `controllers`. I have been testing using my iPhone and other sizes of iPhone and they look great. I tried once on an iPad but it was a border around the screen like in this image. [image]

I constrained to margins and I did not give any height or width constraints so it could stretch properly. It also looks good on the storyboard viewing so what could I be doing wrong? Can't seem to find any resource online to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behaviour when you run iphone app in ipad

This happened  because your app is supported iphone only . 
Tap on your project and select universal if you want to  add support for both iphone and ipad.

Other option is you can check requires full screen check box but it will still show black bar

**Note:** However you are developing **iPhone** Only app but it is compulsory to check that everything works fine in **ipad** because apple review team will also check that in ipad and your app may be rejected if something is not proper

[image]

Comment: that was the issue! I must have set that up without knowing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

May be you have made an iPhone app. Try to change the setting to Universal app in the xcode settings. Normally iPhone app shows scaled on iPad, which is same as in your case.

**Select Projet in xcode -> General Setting**

[image: Deployment Info in Project Settings]